# accessing related record attributes in nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a nested form, that is only used for updates

```
<%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :distances do |distance| %>
    <%= distance.check_box :active %>
```

the form functions in updating the child record.  However I cannot call any attirbute of the related record with either `f`or `distance`prefix

```
    <%= distance.starting_point %>
```

How can this value be rendered?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, it create new object only if not present:

```
<%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :distances, f.object.distances || f.object.build_distances do |distance| %>
    <%= distance.check_box :active %>
    <%= distance.starting_point %>
```

Comment: rails is complaining that `undefined method `distance` for the fields_for tag.  Also, as the question states, this is only for updates..

Comment: you were close.  Invoking the `object` was what was required in the fields_for block.  Useful hint!

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= distance.object.starting_point %>
```

renders the child attribute